# PHP Driver of MongoDB not working on Windows 7

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, php-mongodb

Extract from my php_info() for PHP 5.3.1 is:

System  Windows NT DEBI-PC 6.1 build 7600 ((null)) i586

Build Date  Nov 20 2009 17:20:57

Compiler    MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)

Architecture    x86

Thread Safety   enabled

I have download php_mongo.dll for VC6 and thread-safe and PHP 5.3, pasted it in the ext folder of php run by xampp and added the extension line to php.ini file.

Still I cannot run mongoDB from PHP

Any help?

Comment: Are you using a 64 or 32 bit version of the extension? If you run PHP on the commandline, it will show you startup errors which might be useful as well to find out more. Alternatively, enable error logging and check the error log.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem only on Windows 7 on x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4 builds for Windows VC9 (32bit and 64bit)** https://github.com/downloads/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/php_mongo-1.2.12.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is the new path for this driver https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html